# Oracle/XML error message

Tags: oracle10g

This is my 2nd day working with XML and I have run in to an error message question.

I have a file that is creating an error in Oracle 10g BPEL.  When the file is processed I am getting the following error:
[image]

My question is the @146b11e4 some kind of location?

If it is, is that location someplace I can access or will I need to parse the file and determine what value is returning the 'zero node' and go from there?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I did some more looking and the next summary has some more information:
[image]

If I understand this and the Spec correct there is a [null] somewhere in the incoming file that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Please copy and paste the messages as text (and format as code or quotes if appropriate); not everyone can see images, and the text is hard to read in the image anyway, at least without zooming in.

Comment: Thanks for the note Alex.  The VM I'm working with is having issues with the copy of text from the VM to my main.  I will definitely figure it out for future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @146b11e4 isn't a reference to the file location, it's a memory address for a particular instance of an XMLElement object. If you re-run the process you'll probably see a different memory address. It's just the memory location for the XML document being parsed. So it isn't something you can access, and wouldn't be too useful if you could; it will just contain the contents of your file (more or less).

The 'line "1238"' part looks like a reference to the BPEL code and not to the XML file, unfortunately. It looks like the XML is valid - so parsing it manually or in an XML editor might not reveal anything obvious - but doesn't contain a node that BPEL is expecting, perhaps. But this isn't a tool I use. Without the XML and the BPEL XPath it's not going to be easy to figure out exactly what the problem is.